# How to get position of the clicked item in list view and store it in a variable

Tags: java, android, listview

So I made this list view with 5-6 items. I have set up the onItemClickListener method. I want to get the position of the clicked listView. For ex if on Number One I should get the respective position and save it in the variable. If I click on number two, I should get the respective position and so on . Im a beginner so please explain.

```
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> abcd = new ArrayList<>();
    abcd.add("Number One");
    abcd.add("Number Two");
    abcd.add("Number Three");
    abcd.add("Number Four");
    abcd.add("Number Five");
    abcd.add("Number Six")
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        int position = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked"+position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: `i` is the position of the clicked item. Just read the method documentation and you would have known

Comment: int i  is the position , so make your  toast like this `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked"+i ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: onItemClick...{String item = abcd.get(position);

Comment: I tried it just now and the app kept crashing Idk why. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put you list as a private field;

```
   private List<String> abcd = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in your logic:

```
   final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    abcd.add("Number One");
    abcd.add("Number Two");
    abcd.add("Number Three");
    abcd.add("Number Four");
    abcd.add("Number Five");
    abcd.add("Number Six")
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
       String selectedElement = abcd.get(i);
    }
});
```

The selectedElement will be your element that you can store

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3)
        {
            String selectedFromList =(String) (listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            Log.d("Selected: ",  selectedFromList);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String item = abcd.get(pos);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + item + " At Position: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```